# React Router changes the URL but doesn't render the components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been struggling with this for a while now, I have a page with a Nav containing some Links, and a react router switch which should change the content on the page depending on the url. The issue is that when I click the link the URL in the address bar changes to the correct URL but the content isn't changing.

I have only one instance of BrowserRouter and as far as I can see the switch has the inclusion of 'exact' on the '/' path.

Why is this occurring?

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <RecoilRoot>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </RecoilRoot>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './NavDesktop.css'
import {useRecoilValue} from 'recoil'
import { configState } from '../atoms';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function NavDesktop(){

    const config = useRecoilValue(configState);
    return(
        <div className="container-fluid shadow nav-desktop-container">
            <div className="row nav-desktop-container-row"><div className="col-auto">{config.site_name ?? "LandKit."}</div><div className="col-auto">
              <div className="container nav-items-container">
                <div className="row nav-desktop-items-row">
                    <div className="col-md-auto"><Link to="/recordings">Call Recordings</Link></div>
                    <div className="col-md-auto"><Link to="/charges">Our Charges</Link></div>
                    <div className="col-md-auto"><Link to="/support">Support</Link></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default NavDesktop
```

App.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import InnerPage from './Pages/InnerPage'
import NavMobile from './Components/NavMobile'
import NavDekstop from './Components/NavDesktop'
import Footer from './Components/Footer'
import {BrowserRouter as  Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="container-fluid main-container">
     <div className="row nav-row-main d-flex d-md-none"><NavMobile/></div>
     <div className="row nav-row-main d-none d-md-flex"><NavDekstop/></div>
     <div className="row inner-row-main flex-grow-1">
     
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"><div>home</div></Route>
            <Route path="/recordings"><div>recordings</div></Route>
            <Route path="/charges"><div>Charges</div></Route>
            <Route path="/support"><div>Support</div></Route>
        </Switch>
    
     </div>
      <div className="row nav-row-main"><Footer/></div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You haven't wrapped your charges and support with the div

Comment: @Shyam, thanks, I have updated the question but unfortunately it hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: `import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";`

you already covered your app with browserouter in index.js, so I don't think you need to put it again in app.js. Also switch is a different thing than browserouter.

Comment: Can you please port your code to a codesandbox illustrating the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **app.js** change the import from

```
import {BrowserRouter as  Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

you can import `BrowserRouter` as `Router` in index.js but the way it is done in app.js is incorrect.

**index.js** -> `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";`

`Switch` renders only one route and whichever route is matched first. Since that is imported incorrectly, the route matching is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wrap your routes with both BrowserRouter and Switch. Link uses Switch to change links.

App.js should be:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import InnerPage from './Pages/InnerPage'
import NavMobile from './Components/NavMobile'
import NavDekstop from './Components/NavDesktop'
import Footer from './Components/Footer'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,  Switch , Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container-fluid main-container">
        <div className="row nav-row-main d-flex d-md-none"><NavMobile/></div>
        <div className="row nav-row-main d-none d-md-flex"><NavDekstop/></div>
        <div className="row inner-row-main flex-grow-1">
           <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/"><div>home</div></Route>
             <Route path="/recordings"><div>recordings</div></Route>
             <Route path="/charges"><div>Charges</div></Route>
             <Route path="/support"><div>Support</div></Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
        <div className="row nav-row-main"><Footer/></div>
      </div>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Docs can be referred here: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention in this line:

```js
import {BrowserRouter as  Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

You are wrapping your routes in a Router, not inside a Switch.
You should be doing this:

```js
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```